# I can't install the sqlite3 gem on mac osx 10.8.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, sqlite, rvm

My `bundle install` is not working and I get this error:

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Frank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-       include=/Users/Frank/include --with-sqlite3-lib=/Users/Frank/lib --with-sqlite3-dir=/Users/Frank/bin
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile
```

Which I think it has to do with the libsql-dev thats not working.
but then I get this

```
make
compiling backup.c
In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:51,
             from backup.c:3:
./backup.h:7: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘sqlite3_backup’
backup.c: In function ‘initialize’:
backup.c:63: error: ‘sqlite3_backup’ undeclared (first use in this function)
backup.c:63: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
backup.c:63: error: for each function it appears in.)
backup.c:63: error: ‘pBackup’ undeclared (first use in this function)
backup.c:77: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c: In function ‘step’:
backup.c:101: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c:102: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c: In function ‘finish’:
backup.c:115: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c:116: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c:117: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c: In function ‘remaining’:
backup.c:133: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c:134: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c: In function ‘pagecount’:
backup.c:149: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
backup.c:150: error: ‘sqlite3BackupRuby’ has no member named ‘p’
make: *** [backup.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Frank/gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Frank/gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I started getting it randmoly today and I can't run my rails apps without it. What can I do?

Comment: See https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Himanshu's link fixed my problem.

https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

Was having this issue recently.  Had to open up the XCode tools and accept the terms of service.  Then everything worked fine.  (Make sure you have XCode installed first)